# django: how to get logged in user credantials from terminal and store it in xml

Tags: django, xml-parsing, django-rest-framework, django-users

I have an django project that i have created using django-rest framework and i also have an xml file which contains tags for both username and password. Now i want to store logged-in users username and password in that xml either automatically or throgh terminal using xml parser and save it for the latest details.  please help me to come over this. thanks in advance.

Comment: That sounds like a really bad idea. Why would you want to store passwords in an XML file? For a start, Django doesn't even store the passwords itself, just a hash.

Comment: hmmm the thing is i need to store all the information of the logged in user in an xml,, for that i tried these two to test whether it 'l store or not

Comment: Django does not store password in plain text. You are unlikely to get unencrypted password.

Comment: Then how i can store logged-in user credantials to xml file, is there a way to do this